# JSF 1: execute bean method and set parameters for next page

Tags: jsf, parameters, navigation, action

I'm new to JSF.
What i want is to click on something and when i do i want to run a bean method AND send the request with GET so i can set Parameters that will show on the URL of the next page.

I tried with this navigation-rule, the method will execute and return "success_selectedUserToCard", it will forward me to-view-id but the parameters are removed:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success_selectedUserToCard</from-outcome>-->
        <to-view-id>/jspx/user_to_card.faces?tab=usertocard&amp;selectedLink=usertocardManagementLink</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

So my URL on the following page will be only: /jspx/user_to_card.faces

P.S. I am using JSF 1. Cannot move to JSF 2

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExternalContext#redirect()` instead.

```
public void submit() {
    // Do your job here.
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect("/jspx/user_to_card.faces?tab=usertocard&amp;selectedLink=usertocardManagementLink");
}
```

Nasty, but since you aren't using JSF 2.0 which supports `includeViewParams`, there's no other way.